# Is it possible in AutoFixture SemanticComparison to set custom comparer for specified type

Tags: c#, autofixture, semantic-comparison

Is it possible in [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) SemanticComparison to set custom comparer for specified property of a object or for specified type.

For example you need to compare objects that have property of type DateTime. You want to compare them using Likenes but you want the precision of the comparison to discard differences on milliseconds level (possibly you lost precision after retrieving DateTime from database).

Comment: Related: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/48

Comment: See also https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `EqualsWhen` member of the Likeness (Fluent) API for doing that.

[Here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/67f313c68b779bf63406ffbfdf598d047f82244d/Src/SemanticComparisonUnitTest/LikenessTest.cs#L771) is a quite similar example.